# Creating a PDF from WKWebView in macOS 11.+

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit, wkwebview, appkit

As `WKWebView` contents can finally be printed out in macOS 11+, I'm trying to replace old `WebView` dependencies.

However, with the HTML correctly loaded in `WKWebView`, creating PDF files using `NSPrintJobDisposition: NSPrintSaveJob` produces blank, empty documents. They have the correct page count and sizing, but remain empty. Using the same code without `NSPrintSaveJob` works just fine.

This is how I'm printing the contents:

```objectivec
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo;   
[printInfo.dictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:@{
        NSPrintJobDisposition: NSPrintSaveJob,
        NSPrintJobSavingURL: url
}];

NSPrintOperation *printOperation =[(WKWebView*)_webView printOperationWithPrintInfo:printInfo];
printOperation.view.frame = NSMakeRect(0,0, printInfo.paperSize.width, printInfo.paperSize.height);
    
printOperation.showsPrintPanel = NO;
printOperation.showsProgressPanel = YES;
    
[printOperation runOperation];
```

Setting `showsPrintPanel` as `true` and uncommenting the dictionary will display a normal print dialog, and the result looks completely normal there.

I'm confused about what I am doing wrong, or is printing from `WKWebView` *still* this buggy?

**Sample project:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t220cn8orooorwb/WebkitPDFTest.zip?dl=1

*Create PDF* and *Print* buttons share the same code (found in `PreviewView`), but the other produces an empty file, which is then loaded into the `PDFView`.

#### Further findings

By what I've gathered online, this could be a long-running bug.

It seems that `WKWebView` prefers using its `createPDF` method when creating PDF files in the background, but that method renders what is **displayed on screen**, not the actual document content with page breaks and print stylization. It also appears to ignore some `NSPrintInfo` settings.

Comment: Does this happen for any PDF, or just some PDF's?

Comment: Any PDF. It seems to be a bug which has been present in the view forever, but I've now attached a sample project to the question.

Answer (score 1):

`WKWebView` printing is **very** badly documented. The reason for the blank pages is the run-loop code in WebKit, and all printing must happen **asynchronously**.

This is why `[printOperation runOperation]` / `printOperation.runOperation()` does not work. Instead, you need to call   the strangely named `runOperationModalForWindow`. Although the method name refers to a modal window, you don't *need* to display the modal, but this method somehow makes the print operation asynchronous.

```objectivec
// Create print operation
NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [webView printOperationWithPrintInfo:printInfo];

// Set web view bounds - without this, the operation will crash
printOperation.view.frame = NSMakeRect(0,0, printInfo.paperSize.width, printInfo.paperSize.height);

// Print it out
[printOperation runOperationModalForWindow:self.window delegate:self didRunSelector:@selector(printOperationDidRun:success:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
```

You also need to have a handler method to catch the results:

```objectivec
- (void)printOperationDidRun:(id)operation success:(bool)success contextInfo:(nullable void *)contextInfo {
    // Do something with your print
}
```